# TCP port unusable after crash

Tags: java, android, tcp, port, netty

I'm writing an app in java for android.  I've noticed that if my app crashes, the port my TCP connection was over cannot be used again when I restart the app.  Is there any way to remedy this from the newly restarted apps point of view (not by picking a new port)?  I've discovered turning wifi off and back on is sufficient, or switching to cell from wifi.  The problem is the same with standard TCP java sockets or Netty 4.

Thanks!

Comment: Define ' cannot be used again when I restart the app'.

Comment: io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: /(ip addr):(port)

Answer (score 2):

This option will allow binding to an already bound ip:port combination. It's usually used to be able to restart a server if it crashed/got killed (so while the socket is still in the TIME_WAIT state):

```
bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true);
```

Comment: This did not work (when added to client or server).  Perhaps I should note that the app is acting as a client, while my PC is the server.  Restarting the server also does nothing.

Comment: a TimeoutException makes no sense for me in this scenario, especially if the reboot of the server application doesn't help. dunno then.